# parameter aliases

Tags: shell, alias

For example is it possible if I could something like below.

```
alias sd='sudo su - <parameter>'
```

if I write like below in command prompt.

```
$sd parameter
```

It would sudo me to given ID as parameter.

Also,

```
alias chdr='cd /dir1/dir2/dir3/<parameter>'
$chdr parameter
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply define

```
alias sd='sudo su -'
```

and write

```
sd username
```

You can't pass parameters to an alias, but once the alias has been expanded, the words after it become arguments to the command.

Instead of `sudo su - username`, you could use `sudo -u username -i` (unless your sudo configuration is restricted to running `su`, which doesn't bring any security benefits whatsoever).

If you want anything more complicated, use a function instead of an alias.

```
chdr () {
  cd "/dir1/dir2/dir3/$1"
}
```

You can pass arguments to a function. In the function definition, `"$1"` is replaced by the first parameter, `"$2"` by the second parameter, etc. Don't forget to [put double quotes around variable expansions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters).

For this specific case, you may like `CDPATH`, if your shell supports this feature (check your shell's manual).

Any for the `sudo` use case, you may prefer this function which runs a login shell if it isn't passed any arguments except the user name, or runs the specified command if passed more arguments. `$#` is replaced by the number of arguments, and `"$@"` passes all arguments through unchanged.

```
sd () {
  if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
    sudo -i -u "$1"
  else
    sudo -u "$@"
  fi
}
```

(I assume you use a Bourne-style shell, such as `sh`, `ksh` (any variant), `bash`, `zsh`, etc. (T)csh works differently.)

Answer (score 0):

try this: `alias sd='sudo su - $1'`

Comment: This won't work for the `cd` command due to a stray space: `alias ep='echo "/$1"'; ep` -> `/`, `ep gg` -> `/ gg`

Comment: Tried and tested with sudo, works. Murphy, can you please elaborate

Comment: @Ahmad I'm sure it will work with `sudo`, but you asked for a second construct to append the parameter to a dir list of the `cd` command. I don't think that works due to the space that's inserted before the parameter. Perhaps you should use a script for that one.

Comment: This works only by coincidence, because two mistakes happens to cancel out. It does not pass parameters to the alias. With this definition, `sd foo` expands to `sudo su - $1 foo`. Then, since `$1` is usually empty at an interactive prompt, you get `sudo su - foo`.